# How to implement reading default object settings from a database with oop and soc

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, separation-of-concerns

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Location {
    private int id;
    private String name = "noname";
    ... // other properties

    public Location(int locationId) {
        this.id = locationId;
        this.name = getNameFromDatabase(locationId);
    } 

    public static Map<Integer,Location> getAllLocations() {
        // reads all locations from database and puts objects into a map
    }       

    ... // other methods

}
```

The name property can be defined in one of the following ways using:

1. default value defined by the developer in the source code
2. default application value defined in the database (overrides the developer's default),
3. location specific value defined in the database (overrides both previous' values)

In the application the location object is instantiated by `Map<Integer,Location> locations = Location.getAllLocations();`

**Implementing 1. and 3. is straightforward, but what is the most appropriate way to implement the 2. "application specific default values"**:

- I can get the default value in the getNameFromDatabase method, but then I am seeking for a default value in the database with each and every new location (since it's default, it should be selected only once)
- In location object instantiation I could beforehand read default values into a special location object and then pass this object to the constructor (but I do believe I'd be breaking the separation of concerns)
- **I believe I'd need sort of static singleton which would be instantiated inside the class, but I have no idea how to implement it**

  ### EDIT
- the shown name property is just a snippet from a whole class (there are about 20 properties)
- default application value is also stored in the database; in fact it is in the the same table as other locations, except it has a special id -1; so what I am currently doing in getNameFromDatabase method is `select * from location where location_id in (-1, &lt;locationid&gt;) order by location_id`, but I do believe it is a bad design, since I am reading default location values for each and every location I set
- so what I am looking for is: in method getnamefromdatabase, it first checks if there is a name defined for my location id. if not, check if I already have a *globaly* defined defaultlocationname, if not, find it in database and then define global defaultlocationname.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it, if you have appropriately defined `getNameFromDatabase` and `getApplicationDefaultName` methods.  ( a `setApplicationDefaultName` method should also be defined for setting the application's name for a given locationId  )

```
private int id;
private String name =- "noname"; // default in source code?

public Location(int locationId) {
    // ...
    String appName = Location.getApplicationDefaultName();
    String dbName = getNameFromDatabase(locationId);
    if(dbName != null) {
        this.name = dbName;
    } else if (appName != null) {
        this.name = appName;
    } // else name will default to initially set value.
}
```

When you assign name with the statement `this.name = getNameFromDatabase(locationId)`, you are overwriting the value previously assigned to `this.name`, so your case 1 will not be realized.  Your logic for assigning the name (or any of your properties with the expected behavior to be described by your points 1,2, & 3) should be:

```
if (db has specific name)
    use db specific name              // point 3
else if (db has default name)         // point 2
    use db default name
else
    don't overwrite source code name  //point 1
```

**Edit**

One way of separating the concern of retrieving the default database value from what practice you use to retrieve that value (once per VM, or every time, or just sometimes depending on the phase of the moon) is by using the [Strategy](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/strategy.html) design pattern. The interface `RetrievalMethod` should have one method, `getDefaultFromDatabase()`, whose behavior can be specified by implementers.  Doing this, your Location's `getApplicationDefaultName` method (along with the `RetrievalMethod` strategy setting method) will look like:

```
private RetrievalMethod myLocationRetriever = GenericRetrievalMethod(/*...*/);
// ...
public void setLocationRetrievalMethod(RetrievalMethod retr) {
    myLocationRetriever = retr;
}
// ... 
private String getApplicationDefaultName() {
    myLocationRetriever.getDefaultFromDatabase();
}
```

Per your application specs, you can set `myLocationRetriever` to the appropriate behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question, getapplicationdefaultname() also reads its values from a database (from the same table as getnamefromdatabase, except that default location settings have a special id -1).

Comment: As you stated in your edit, you are getting the default name from the database everytime you check whether a location specific name exists in your DB.  It might be more efficient to cache the result from one call to see whether an application specific name exists in your DB, and then only query for location specific name, if it exists, reverting to the cache if it doesn't, and finally reverting to dev defined default if neither of the above work.  But the overhead of querying for any data is probably washing out whatever overhead you're getting from selecting an additional possible row from DB

Comment: OK, but the (db has default name) always checks the database, what I wanted with my question is, how to avoid checking the database every time new object is created. It would check the first time, create the new defaultobject which would be visible to all other objects so next time, i'd read data just from the internal object. But I know how to achive this, by creating default object externally, which breaks SoC

Comment: @zeldi, I edited my question with one method of keeping SoC by using the Strategy pattern.